# How to convert array to object then assign to new variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, ionic3

I want to convert data stored in one variable from an array to an object, then assign that converted data to another variable.

For example, take:

```
options = ["226:39"];
```

and convert `["226:39"]` to `{"226":"39"}`, then assign the converted data to the `convertedOptions` variable.

How would I do that?

Comment: options[0] is your string, .split(":") it then compose your object with the resulting 2 string elements.

Comment: what if the case is different this time. lets say the array contains ["226:39:45"] i want first 2 values from array assign to one variable, and the 3rd value assigned to another variable for example : {"226":"39"} and {"45"} how would i achieve that. if you could demonstrate it code snippet that would be awesome.

Comment: reason for all this is the first 2 values in the array is the option_value and option_value_id which is required by opencart api to add an item to cart. the 3rd value is the option price which associated with the specific option. so i want to add the 3rd value to the product price. so i can deduct the right amount from the customer when they are paying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the other answers are correct for the sample value you mentioned in the question, using substring instead of split will handle the case where the value may need to contain a ":" character.

```
var options = ["226:39", "ratio:226:39"];
var convertedOptions = {};
for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++){
var separatorIndex = options[i].indexOf(":");
    if(separatorIndex > -1) {
        var name = options[i].substring(0, separatorIndex);
        var value = options[i].substring(separatorIndex + 1, options[i].length);
        convertedOptions[name] = value;
    }
}
console.log(convertedOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by spliting the element of options by ':':

```js
var options = ["226:39"];
convertedOptions = {};
var el = options[0].split(':');
convertedOptions[el[0]] = el[1];
console.log(convertedOptions);
```

OR:

```js
var options = ["226:39"];
convertedOptions = {};
var [prop, value] = options[0].split(':');
convertedOptions[prop] = value;
console.log(convertedOptions);
```

OR:

```js
var options = ["226:39"];
var [prop, value] = options[0].split(':');
convertedOptions = { [prop]: value };
console.log(convertedOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `split` the string using the : separator, create your `convertedOptions` object, and then assign.

```js
var options = ['226:39'];
var splitOptions = options[0].split(':');
var convertedOptions = {};
convertedOptions[splitOptions[0]] = splitOptions[1];
console.log(convertedOptions);
```

Comment: what if the case is different this time. lets say the array contains ["226:39:45"] i want first 2 values from array assign to one variable, and the 3rd value assigned to another variable for example : {"226":"39"} and {"45"} how would i achieve that. if you could demonstrate it code snippet that would be awesome.

Comment: reason for all this is the first 2 values in the array is the option_value and option_value_id which is required by opencart api to add an item to cart. the 3rd value is the option price which associated with the specific option. so i want to add the 3rd value to the product price. so i can deduct the right amount from the customer when they are paying.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string and map an object for each element of `options` for a new property.

```js
var options = ["226:39"],
    convertedOptions = Object.assign(
        ...options.map(a => (([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v }))(a.split(':')))
    );
    
console.log(convertedOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [String#replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to format the string as JSON, and then convert to an object using [JSON#parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```js
var options = ["226:39"];

var convertedOptions = JSON.parse(options[0].replace(/([^:]+):([^:]+)/, '{"$1":$2}'));

console.log(convertedOptions);
```